# Farseer setup in Visual studio to work with C# and XNA

Tags: c#, visual-studio, xna, farseer

I have downloaded the folder containing the Farseer Physics engine. and I have a game that I am working on using C# and XNA. 
The issue Im having is that I dont know how to add the files for Farseer to my project so i can reference the functions in the code.
How Do I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I spent about 3 hours trying to figure this one out. (sounds stupid, I know)
After I posted this question I ran on to another question on here that I'm sure I looked at already.
ANSWER: Just drag and drop the stupid folder into the Solution Explorer.

Answer (score 5):

You could also:

1. Open the Farseer project
2. Build it
3. Go into your own project
4. Right click on 'references' in solution explorer and choose 'add reference'
5. Browse to the FarseerPhysics .dll file and select it
6. You now have added it as a reference to your project and can use it in your code!

Comment: Great simple guide! As of ver 3.3.x, the 'FarseerPhysicsXNA.dll' locates in .\Farseer Physics Engine 3.3.1 XNA\obj\x86\Debug\